# How to Install NVIDIA Drivers on Ubuntu Server

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I'm trying to set up CUDA and install a proper NVIDIA driver for my GT 710 on my server so I can do things like train RNN models on it, but it seems like they're all designed for desktops.

`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` lists the following:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000128Bsv00001043sd000085E7bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

But the installation for any of these drivers always fails and tries to install things like GNOME when all I want is the driver.

How can I properly install an NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu server?

Comment: Does this help? https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07

Comment: It would be better if you created an answer outlining and explaining the steps that you took for your particular configuration. I would like to see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I initially stated in my question, attempting to install the driver on my Ubuntu 20.04 server OS didn't work (maybe it's a bug, I'm not sure), but I've detailed the exact steps I took below, which worked for me.

After getting the driver to work, I could just install CUDA the standard way.

#### Remove Any Previous Installations (*IMPORTANT*)

I tried to install the driver via `apt` previously, which failed, so I had to ensure any previous NVIDIA packages were removed. I ran the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

#### Download the Driver

For me, I chose the 460.67 driver, which is the latest production branch version at the time of writing this. I ran the following commands:

```
cd ~/
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/460.67/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.67.run
```

#### Install Dependencies

Execute the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib dkms`.

#### Execute the Runfile

```
cd ~/
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.67.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.67.run
```

Follow all the prompts the installer gives.

**During installation, you may get a warning similar to the one below. It is perfectly safe to ignore.**

```
WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib' and X module path '/usr/lib/xorg/modules'; these paths were not queryable from the system.  If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.
```

#### Check the Installation

You can check if everything was installed correctly by running the command `nvidia-smi`, which should return a similar-looking output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.67       Driver Version: 460.67       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 710      On   | 00000000:07:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2000MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you see that, then your NVIDIA driver is correctly installed!

Comment: Were you able to install tensorflow / pytorch and able to run models after your installation? I had the same requirement but was disappointed to not see NVidia GT 710 in the CUDA Compute Capability list.